# How to convert these few dockerfile commands into linux bash commands

Tags: bash, docker

I need to configure the SSH service in my container of  docker for remote debugging 
I read the Dockerizing an SSH Service and get the dockerfile. However, for various reasons, I need to enter the container to configure SSH using the bash command line.

There are 4 dockerfile commands I don’t know how to convert to bash
commands, please help me.

```sh
ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile
EXPOSE 22 7777
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Comment: Usually you wouldn't either install an ssh daemon in a container (port mapping, user identity, and especially all of the credentials involved are _very_ tricky to get right, and running multiple processes in one container adds a lot of complexity) or do lots of work in an interactive shell; I'd try to revisit your approach to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
# set Environmentvariable
export NOTVISIBLE="in users profile"

# append 'export VISIBLE=now' to /etc/profile
echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

# start ssh daemon in foreground
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

EXPOSE derives ports 22 and 7777 from the container and can not be set using a bash script. This must be done when creating the container.

Comment: thans very much.Here are two more docker commands. Can you also convert them? 
          ADD . /code
         WORKDIR /code

Comment: Both commands are part of container construction. The first copies everything from the current directory '.' to `/code` in the container. The second defines the working directory. In the container it could be 'simulated' with a `cd /code`.